# javascript handleClick-function wrong syntax? for-loop

Tags: javascript, function

Hi all you excellent developers here,

I've problem with a javascript function, handleClick.
In the for-loop it looks like this and it works (console shows all the parameters connected to the products-variable when clicking on the shopButton):

```
shopButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    handleClick(products[i]);
});
```

I have already a function in the script that should add to cart, this one:

```
addItem(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
}
```

I try to drive that function to get the product from the loop in to the cart. But I can't get it right....

```
handleClick(productClicked) {
    productClicked.addItem(item);
}
```

(item) is not defined is the answer and I can't find a way to get the products from the handleClick in the loop to the drive-function (addItem).

Could anyone help...? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where does `item` come from?

Comment: Are you adding multiple event listeners to the same `shopButton` in the loop? That's probably not what you want.

Comment: the function addItem(item). But in the loop the variable is products.

Comment: No, I mean `item` in `handleClick()`. Which item is it supposed to add to the product that was clicked?

Comment: I think you need to add your HTML and show how the loop is connected to it. I suspect you have everything backwards.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, but the eventlistener isn't the problem...

Comment: How does the user specify which item they're adding to the cart when they click on the shop button?

Comment: HTML

 <ul id="products-content" data-name="products-content">
        </ul>

javascript
let ul = document.getElementById("products-content");

for(let i = 0; i <products.length; i++) {

Comment: Is `products[i]` supposed to be the item? You're using it as `productClicked`

Comment: It seems like it should actually be `cart.addItem(productClicked)`

Comment: Yes, Barmar, thats for sure, I've things backwards - but i don't know exactly what and how to solve it. Thanks anyone:)

Comment: I'll try that, thanks! @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

`productClicked` is not the shopping cart, it's the product that you want to add to the cart. So it should be

```
handleClick(productClicked) {
    shoppingCart.addItem(productClicked);
}
```

Replace `shoppingCart` with the actual name of the variable holding the cart.